# Permalink base only for posts

Tags: posts, customization, permalinks, pages

I am looking for special permalink mod, is this possible:

For posts to be like this:
www.example.com/blog/nameofthepost

For pages to be like this:
www.example.com/nameofthepage

Is this possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your desired structure:

Go to **Settings > Permalinks** in Admin.

Under **Common Settings**, click **Custom Structure** and enter `/blog/%postname%/`

Click **Save Changes** button.

This sets the permalink structure for posts. Pages already appear at at the root of your install, so no modification is needed for that.

Comment: It's worth noting, while this won't affect the permalinks for pages, it will affect the permalinks for categories and tags, and also has the potential to affect custom post types, etc.

Comment: Any idea if there's a way to do this without messing with CPT URL structure?